# binding directories in Singularity

Tags: singularity-container

I haven't found information on the internet about if there is a command in singularity to show what are the default directory bindings between the host and the container. Also, if there is a command to show the bindings when a specific image is run with `singularity run myimage.sif`. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

From the [singularity user docs](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.10/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html#system-defined-bind-paths):

> In the default configuration, the system default bind points are `$HOME`, `/sys:/sys` , `/proc:/proc`, `/tmp:/tmp`, `/var/tmp:/var/tmp`, `/etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf`, `/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd`, and `$PWD`.

The admin docs also explain how to [configure and modify the default binds](https://singularity-admindoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/the_singularity_config_file.html#mount-proc-sys-dev-home-tmp-boolean-default-yes).